# Redactor - How to implement stripTags API call?

Tags: javascript, redactor, redactor.js

I want to strip all HTML tags except the `<a>` tag from redactor. I found this handy API call called [stripTags](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/api/clean/#api-stripTags) but I don't know how to use it with my current code. Any ideas?

**API**

```
var html = this.clean.stripTags(html, '<a>');
```

**JS**

```
  $(function()
    {
      $('.text-editor-strip').redactor();
  });
```

**Attempt**

If the `stripTag` is anywhere in the function then it stops Redactor from initialising as below.

```
 $(function()
   {
     var html = this.clean.stripTags(html, '<a>');
     $('.text-editor-strip').redactor();
 });
```

Comment: Are you trying to strip tags from pasted content?

Comment: No it's a sub-heading. We want to keep redactor for adding links but sometimes it injects <p> tags which mess with the layout so trying to strip those out.

Comment: Is it just the `<p>` tags you need to remove then?

Comment: Yep, just those pesky <p> tags.

Comment: Sorry I just saw that <div> and <br> tags are also causing issues.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `paragraphize` setting you can turn off to eliminate the `<p>` tags. You can enable it when you initialize redactor:

```
$('#redactor').redactor({
  paragraphize: false
});
```

This will use `<br/>` tags in place of paragraphs tags.

Here's a [demo](http://codepen.io/brettdewoody/pen/akyJdg?editors=1111).

Comment: Hi, thanks I saw this. I thought it was a winner but then I uncovered instances where divs & br tags were also causing issues. Sorry to mislead you.